# Как вывести запись несколько раз?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id, name, more_info_url 
FROM services 
WHERE id IN (1,7,10,12,7) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,7,10,12,7)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при таком запросе запись с id=7 вывелась дважды. как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таком оно дважды не выведется. Можно так

```
SELECT id, name, more_info_url 
FROM services 
WHERE id = 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name, more_info_url 
FROM services 
WHERE id = 7 UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name, more_info_url 
FROM services 
WHERE id = 7
...
```

Ну вообще, смысла в такой выборке нет.

Comment: мне нужно вывести услуги из заказа, в порядке следования. они могут повторяться. как тогда это сделать?
Может создать массив, в него записать результаты выборки для каждого id, а потом вытаскивать из массива? Всяко получится оптимальнее, чем сто раз дёргать по строчке из бд.

Comment: Конечно, оптимальнее, так и делайте.